Determine approximate paint colors from photo
I would like to copy the color scheme of this cabin when building a cabin of my own.
Is there a way to determine the approximate colour of red and grey from the photo?

Source: https://highlandoutbuildings.com/

Do you want your shed to look like the picture of that shed, or do you want your shed to look like that other shed looks 'in real life'? If the former, then easy-peasy - take the pic down to your local paint store and compare their wall of color swatches to the colors in the pic until you're happy you've found a match. If it's the latter, then you have a problem, because you don't know enough about the exposure or color-balance of the picture to be able to tell what that shed looks like irl.

ask Highland Outbuildings

@jsotola I did. No answer.

It is impossible to ascertain a certain color from a picture. Even if a picture is taken to a paint store and used in their computer to formulate a mixture the color will look different when applied to a building outside.
Additionally the color will look different depending on the light it is exposed to as well as the color of other things around it that may be reflecting light onto the painted surface.
What you need to do is get samples ( of red and grey in your case) and paint various spots on your cabin.  Then pick the color that you like the best. Also look at the color different times of the day and be sure you like it.  (An experience with MIL's house showed a color that was wonderfully pale yellow in the sun, looked like a horrible green in the shade.)
Trying to pick a color from a pic of anything can end in great disappointment.

Also, the color seen in the picture is only an interpretation made by the camera by adjusting the white balance. Or if it was a picture taken in RAW, an interpretation by the photographer. Still, an interpretation/approximation.

There are almost endless "color chooser/picker" software programs available for any computer or phone capable of displaying photos. The Firefox  web browser has one built-in, for instance. They will provide a simple 3- or 4- number color code for any point in the photo you choose, which will be accurate enough for any ordinary purpose.

Those are almost certainly factory applied colors on the metal siding panels and not painted after putting on the building. Probably checking with your local metal siding/roofing supplier will give you a range of factory colors to choose from - probably will be certainly close enough for your desired color scheme.  Or you could just reach out to the manufacturer of that building you linked to and they might have insight on what specific colors or suppliers they used.
